# Android: How to Make toast when ProgressDialog finishes

Tags: android, process, toast

I have an activity in which a user needs to download some databases from external source.

I want to add toast when download is finished or on ProgressDialog dismiss. Can you please help me out, here's my ProgressDialog ..

```
ProgressDialog barProgressDialog;
Handler updateBarHandler;

{
    updateBarHandler = new Handler();}


public void launchRingDialog(View view) {
    final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(EmailHacker.this, "Please wait ...",  "Downloading data...", false);
    ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Use `runOnUiThread` to show the `Toast` within `Thread`

Comment: Try to use AsyncTask class in your application and make sure whatever UI is there use within onPostExecute method. and also used Toast in onPostExecute method.

Comment: Use AsyncTask for long running tasks... you can find a lot of examples about it.

Comment: See my Ans below and please tell does it work accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

To call AsyncTask-

```
new Task1().execute();
```

Code-

```
class Task1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() 
            {
            super.onPreExecute();
            final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(EmailHacker.this, "Please wait ...",  "Downloading data...", false);
            ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0)
            {
               try {
                //Do something...
                Thread.sleep(30000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
            {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(EmailHacker.this, "Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try follwin instead of `Thread` in your `public void launchRingDialog()` method,you can specify `params...` of your need but I have set `Void`:

```
final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog;
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(EmailHacker.this, "Please wait ...",  "Downloading data...", false);

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // your task here
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(EmailHacker.this, "Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
```

for further on `AsyncTask` please see [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Comment: It worked, thnx but i also need a processbar for custom time and when it finishes after the set time, a toast will appear. Thnx in advance

Comment: I think time for displaying the `ProgressDialog` depends on the time taken by `doInBackground()` method, If answer worked for you then please accept!

Comment: I know that, thnx for the help, can you please correct my code above. What i need is a toast on processbar dismiss and my process dialog starts on  a button OnClick="launchRingDialog" 
I just want my code to be modified,

Comment: @user3405165 that code looks great, why do you want modification in that/

Answer (score -1):

In the **run()** method of your Runnable, replace `ringProgressDialog.dismiss();` with the following:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(yourContext, "Toast text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

You can make changes to the UI thread only through the UI thread. That is why we are using **runOnUiThread()**

This code can be simplified if you use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Process dialog is not finishing & toast doesn't appear.

Comment: I have edited the answer accordingly. I didn't notice the error which you already had in your code. You can't dismiss the dialog from other threads

Comment: Now, it force closes my app after the set time for process dialog finish.